# Displaying Font Awesome icon above button text

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I need a button to look like the button in the image:

When I add the fontawesome icon to the button it shows, but I'd like it to display on top of the text if that's possible?

```css
.button-examples {
  background-color: #0C3E7e;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="button-examples">
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    See client examples
</button>
```

[image: Button]

Comment: Add `.button-examples i { display: block; }` to force a line break

Comment: Wow. That simple. You can add that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: More simple will be to [just use a p tag?](https://jsfiddle.net/ut84xfjc/)

Comment: Interesting @window.document. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Note that `<p>` usually has margin applied to it by the browser, so you may have to override it with `.button-examples p { margin: 0; }` to prevent unwanted spacings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
.button-examples i {
  display: block;
}
```

to force a line-break between the icon and the text. See: https://jsfiddle.net/9b5304ps/

Answer (score 2):

Just add `<br/>` like this,

```
<button class = "button-examples">
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><br/>
    See client examples
</button>
```

OR, simple make you icon as block level element

```
.button-examples i{
      display:block;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/varidiqede/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/9ahf4ymg/

```
<button class = "button-examples">
    <i class="fa fa-users icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>
      See client examples
    </p>
</button>
```

And css

```
.icon{
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}
.button-examples{
    background-color:#0C3E7e;
    margin-top:50px;
    height:130px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-weight:600;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flex-direction: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) in `.button-examples` like so:

```css
.button-examples {
  display: flex;
  /* The direction in which lines of text are stacked */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0C3E7e;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

.button-examples p {
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="button-examples">
  <i class="fas fa-users fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <p>See client examples</p>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in a block element (`<p>`, `<div>`, etc). Details commented in HTML\CSS.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #0C3E7e;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px; /* Center icon and text */
  width: 130px; /* Needs width defined */
  height: 130px; 
  border-radius: 15px; /* One value for four identical sizes*/
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff; /* As per screenshot */
}

/* A block element (<p>) is wrapped around text in order
to place it under the icon and allow it to have a
different font-size than the icon */
.button p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="button">
<!--.fa-3x makes icon 3 times the regular size-->
    <i class="fas fa-users fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>See client examples</p>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use the code below.

HTML code:
    <button class = "button-examples">
      <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      See client examples
    </button>

CSS code: 
   .button-examples {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    background: #0C3E7e;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.button-examples i{
    font-size:45px;
}
```